# Idiomatic Clojure version of Python's KeyError

Tags: python, clojure, idioms

How should this python be expressed

```
gl_enums = ... # map from name to values for opengl enums
# use with gl_enums["enum name"]
```

in clojure? This works, but is it right?

```
(def gl-enums ...) ; map from name to values for opengl enums
(defn gl-enum [k] (or (gl-enums k) (throw (SomeException.))))
; use with (gl-enum :enum-name)
```

edit: for clarification, this question is about the exception-throwing part, not the map-defining part

Comment: I think your example is the most idiomatic clojure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original example is OK. Two approaches you are also likely to come across:

```
;; not very idiomatic
(defn example
  [m]
  (if (contains? m :name)
    (:name m)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. (format "key %s is missing" :name)))))

;; idiomatic
(defn example
  [m]
  (if-let [v (:name m)]
    v
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. (format "key %s is missing" :name)))))
```

[More on clojure.core/if-let](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/if-let)
[More on clojure.core/contains?](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/contains_q)

Answer (score -1):

Just use a regular hashmap:

```
(def gl-enums {:name1 "value1", :name2 "value2",
               :name3 "value3", ...})
```

if you don't want to provide keywords (like `:keyword`) but prefer strings, you'll need to use `(get gl-enums str)` in `gl-enum`

Comment: wut?  i think the question is asking how best to throw an exception if there is no entry in a map.

Comment: @andrewcooke: yes. yes, it is.